# How to color entries in emacs's ibuffer by buffer type?

Tags: emacs

How can I color entries in ibuffer accoding to the buffer type ?

Based on which mode the buffer is - for example python mode is blue, lisp mode is yellow etc ...

Is this possible ?

Comment: You want to customize the variable `ibuffer-fontification-alist`.  Have a look at the doc-string for examples:  `M-x describe-variable RET ibuffer-fontification-alist RET`  The default value contains an example for `dired-mode` and `ibuffer-help-buffer-modes` -- so just add additional entries for `python-mode`, `emacs-lisp-mode`, etc.  I'm at work now and consequently do not have time at the moment to write up an answer -- however, the comment should be enough for you to answer the question yourself if you'd like.  Either use `setq` to redefine everything, or `add-to-list` to add additional.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comment from @lawlist, here's some sample code you could use and tweak to your liking:

```
(setq ibuffer-fontification-alist
      '((1 (eq major-mode 'c++-mode) yellow-face)
        (1 (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode) green-face)
        (1 (member major-mode '(shell-mode sh-mode)) purple-face)
        (1 (eq major-mode 'tcl-mode) brown-face)))

(defface yellow-face '((t :foreground "yellow")) "")
(defface green-face '((t :foreground "green")) "")
(defface purple-face '((t :foreground "black")) "")
(defface brown-face '((t :foreground "brown")) "")
```

Obviously you can use existing faces, or create new ones (like in this example).  See the [manual for faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html#Faces) for more information.